# Can we use FileLogTraceListener in c# compact framework

Tags: c#-3.0

I Want to debug my program in c# with compact framwork. Please tell me the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are really after because your title and question don't really align.
You can easily debug a compact framework application using the visual studio debugger.  Visual Studio allows you to either run an emulator or to connect to the device and debug directly on the device.
To debug on the device you may need to download Windows Mobile Device center so your device can connect to your pc.

If you are more interested in logging info on the compact framework.  log4net works great.